# Is there a difference between use const keyword inside typedef and outside typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have written a typedef like the following:

```
typedef wchar_t *cString;
```

and I put the const keyword independently as follow:

```
void func(const cString)
```

But when passing `wstring::c_str()` to the previous method `func(wstring::c_str())`, it tells me there's an error `argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "cString"`, although the type `cString` is `wchar_t *` with an independent `const`.

and to resolve that problem I must either define the typedef as `typedef const wchar_t *cString;` or use `const wchar_t*` directly without typedef.

**Why that problem occurred?**

Comment: `void func(const cString)` is the same as `void func(wchar_t* const);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typedef wchar_t *cString;` declares `cString` as a mutable pointer to mutable data.

`const cString` declares a `const` one of these, which is therefore a `const` pointer to mutable data.  The matching typedef for this would be `typedef wchar_t(*const cString);`, I think. (One wouldn't normally typedef a `const` pointer like this, so I'm not 100% certain on the syntax)

However, `wstring::c_str()` returns a mutable pointer to `const` data. The matching typedef for this would be `typedef (const wchar_t) *cString;`, with or without parenthesis.

Therefore `func(wstring::c_str())` is passing a (mutable) pointer to const data, to a function that expects a (const) pointer to mutable data.  The pointer itself can be converted from mutable to `const`, but the data it points to can't be silently converted from `const` to mutable, so it tells you something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is of type `const wchar_t *` (a.k.a. `wchar_t const *`).

Your parameter is of type `wchar_t * const` (the "independent `const`" goes last).

[There is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).